# MySQL - on which columns to use indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  `Games`.`id`, `Games`.`name`, `Games`.`url` 
FROM 
  `Games`
LEFT JOIN 
  `GamesRuns` 
ON 
  Games.id = GamesRuns.game_id 
WHERE 
  (GamesRuns.date >= '2012-07-17 13:14:08') AND (Games.score = 0) AND (Games.active = 1) AND (Games.display = 1) 
GROUP BY 
  `Games`.`id` 
ORDER BY 
  SUM(GamesRuns.count) DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

I want to ask on which columns I should put indexes. I think it should be on GamesRuns.date and Games.score + Games.active + Games.display as multiindex. And I think that to put an index on GamesRuns.count is pointless because it's in SUM function, but otherwise (without SUM function) there should be also an index. Is it right? Because when I use EXPLAIN, it shows me that possible_key and also key is PRIMARY, but PRIMARY is just Games.id. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can't help you unless you post some sample data, and the rest of your table structure. Also, you should run an EXPLAIN SELECT [...] to find out more too.

Comment: Start reading this - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd want an index on anything used for a join and anything used in the where if possible.

MySql doesn't support functional indexes as far as I know (I don't actually use it) so you can't put an index on the SUM function. Someone will correct me if I'm wrong I'm sure

So for your example I'd put an index on Games.id, GamesRuns.game_id, GamesRuns.date, Games.score, Games.active, Games.display

Answer (score 0):

because you are using the field games.id inside the where and also in the group by, the field whould be good.

also the field gamesruns.game_id.

date, score and active and display are also candidates. but in that case you should take care how many records you have. So the rest is up to you and depends on a deeper research on the data.

all the best

Comment: Can I rely that MySQL always use best index? For example use Games.id (PRIMARY) instead of Games.active AND Games.score AND Games.display?

Comment: in general the optimizer isn't that bad. I there are any doubts "explain" the statement